# How to interrupt a Say verb to Gather input?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I have a somewhat long-running Say verb during a phone call that I'd like the caller to answer at any point before the end without having to listen to the entire Say block.

How would I accomplish this?

Here's my current attempt to wrap the Say within a Gather block, but it never speaks the Say verb:

```
    [Route("ask")]
    public TwiMLResult AskQuestions()
    {
        var response = new VoiceResponse();

        var gather = response.Gather(input: new List<Gather.InputEnum> { Gather.InputEnum.Speech },
                                     action: new Uri($"{_baseUrl}{Url.Action(nameof(ReceiveResponse))}"),
                                     method: "POST",
                                     actionOnEmptyResult: true,
                                     bargeIn: true);
        
        gather.Say(voice: _voice, message: @"This is some long-winded TTS that I would like the caller to be able to interrupt by saying anything.");

        return new TwiMLResult(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As usual... I find my own answer almost immediately after posting to SO.

Here's what I should have done:

```
[Route("ask")]
public TwiMLResult AskQuestions()
{
    var response = new VoiceResponse();

    var gather = new Gather(input: new List<Gather.InputEnum> { Gather.InputEnum.Speech },
                                 action: new Uri($"{_baseUrl}{Url.Action(nameof(ReceiveResponse))}"),
                                 method: "POST",
                                 actionOnEmptyResult: true,
                                 bargeIn: true);
    
    gather.Say(voice: _voice, message: @"This is some long-winded TTS that I would like the caller to be able to interrupt by saying anything.");
    response.Append(gather);
    return new TwiMLResult(response);
}
```